# EPPlus Adding VBA Code Corrupts resulting xlsx file

Tags: excel, vb.net, xlsx, epplus, xlsm

I'm creating an excel file using EPPlus from a datatable and saving it to a file, all fairly standard. This works without any hassles. However, if I create a vba project, and add any vba code, the resulting .xlsx file is suddenly corrupted. When try and open it with 2013, you get the standard error.

> "Excel cannot open the file 'xyz.xlsx' because the file format or file
>   extension is not valid. Verify that the file extension matches the
>   format of the file.

If I change the extension to .xls, the file opens ok, and the script runs fine. I'm on the latest beta of Epplus (4.5.0.1). Should I just change the file extension and stick to .xls, or is there something amiss?

```
ExcelPackage.Workbook.CreateVBAProject()
ExcelPackage.Workbook.CodeModule.Code = "'Script is here"
Dim FInfo as new FileInfo("C:\Myfiles\ThisFile.xlsx")
ExcelPackage.SaveAs(FInfo)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not add VBA code to XLSX file format.
Take a look at [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Save-a-workbook-in-another-file-format-6a16c862-4a36-48f9-a300-c2ca0065286e)

> **.xlsx:**
>
> The default XML-based file format for Excel 2007-2013. Cannot store
>   Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications (VBA) macro code or Microsoft
>   Office Excel 4.0 macro sheets (.xlm).

Also take a look at [here](http://professor-excel.com/xlsx-xlsm-xlsb-file-types/)
 to see differences between different formats:

> XLSM If you include VBA macros in your XLSX file, you will be asked to
>   change the file extension to XLSM. Only that way you can save your
>   macro within the Excel file (there are other file types possible, e.g.
>   XLSB – but you can’t use XLSX for VBA macros)

Save your file as XLSM and it should work.